# JavaScript is returning NAN for a string '021519' on html

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have a formatted date as a string '021519' using javascript which return NAN on display in html.
Note I have a xslt using the javascript.

```
                var newDate = '';
                var formatedDate = new Date(date);
                var year = formatedDate.getFullYear().toString();
                var month = (1 + formatedDate.getMonth()).toString();
                if(parseInt(month) < 10)
                {
                    month = "0" + month;
                }
                var day = formatedDate.getDate().toString();

                if(dateFormat == '1')
                {
                    newDate = month + day + year.substr(2,4);
                }
                else
                {
                    newDate = month + day + year;
                }

                    var newLeftStart3 = parseInt(startPosition) - 1;
                    var newLeftEnd3 = newLeftStart + newDate.length;

                    var newRightStart3 =  parseInt(endPosition) - newDate.length;
                    var newRightEnd3 =  newRightStart + newDate.length;

                    if(alignment == '1')
                    {
                        addendaSpace = addendaSpace.substr(0, newLeftStart3) +  newDate + addendaSpace.substr(newLeftEnd3);
                    }

                    if(alignment == '2')
                    {
                        addendaSpace = addendaSpace.substr(0, newRightStart3) +  newDate + addendaSpace.substr(newRightEnd3);
                    }
```

newDate is displaying as NaN i hope this code helps.

Comment: Post your code, cant help otherwise

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark, but maybe `parseInt` is what you need.

Comment: Okay so where is the code that does the translation which causes NAN? Right now your question is unanswerable.

Comment: I have posted the code may be it helps now

Answer (score 0):

I usually format dates in javascript this way:

var d = new Date();

var date = d.getDate();

var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based

var year = d.getFullYear();

console.log(date + "-" + month + "-" + year);